# Why does jQuery insert value attribute in HTML, yet document.getElementById(...).value does not? Is there a workaround?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document

If I use this line in JavaScript,

```
$("#formfieldid").attr("value", "foobar");
```

It inserts the value attribute into the HTML such that it'll appear when viewing the source.

If I use this line in JavaScript,

```
document.getElementById("formfieldid").value = "foobar";
```

The value of the field will be foobar, but it won't show up under view source.

What I want to do is have the attribute NOT show up under view source and use jQuery.  Does there exist an equivalent in jQuery?

Comment: If you are doing this so it doesn't show in the source, may I ask why?

Comment: Thank you very much.  That did work.  I'm copying a password field and I don't want the average joe to see it.  Obviously, someone who is familiar with JS won't have a problem.  But much of the reasoning has to do with passing PCI Compliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the property of elements as opposed to the attribute

```
$("#formfieldid").prop("value", "foobar");
```

If `.prop()` (v1.6+) is not available use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) as its a short cut for the value property.

```
    $("#formfieldid").val("foobar");
```

Answer (score 2):

> What I want to do is have the attribute NOT show up under view source and use jQuery. Does there exist an equivalent in jQuery?

Use `val()` instead. `val()` manipulates the `value` property (like the `prop()` method), while the `attr()` manipulates the attributes via `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()`.

Answer (score 1):

You didnt specify what element you are using, but i think this is what you are looking for.

[jQuery val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#formfieldid").val("foobar");
```